# Extending a 2-form on the Torus

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I am looking for a proof verification on the following problem:

> Let $M : = S^1 \times S^1$ with coordinate chart (inverse) $\phi : (0,2 \pi) \times (0, 2\pi) \rightarrow M$ given by $\phi(x , y) : = (e^{ix} , e^{iy})$. Show that $dx \wedge dy$ extends to a global 2-form that represents a nontrivial class in $H_{\text{dR}}^2(M)$.

In order to extend $dx \wedge dy$, let $\psi: (\pi, 3 \pi) \times (\pi, 3 \pi) \rightarrow M$ be given by $\psi(u , v) = (e^{iu} , e^{iv})$. It is not hard to show that $M =\operatorname{Im} \phi \cup \operatorname{Im} \psi$, that the transition maps between $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ are 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x = u - \pi \quad \quad \quad \quad u = x + \pi \\
y = v - \pi \quad \quad \quad \quad v = y + \pi\\
\end{eqnarray*}
and $dx \wedge dy = du \wedge dv$ on $\operatorname{Im} \phi \cap \operatorname{Im} \psi$. If we define 
$$
\omega  : =\begin{cases}
dx \wedge dy & \text{ on } \operatorname{Im} \phi\\
du \wedge dv & \text{ on } \operatorname{Im} \psi\\
\end{cases}
$$
then $\omega$ is well-defined because $dx \wedge dy = du \wedge dv$ on $\operatorname{Im} \phi \cap \operatorname{Im} \psi$, smooth, and extends $dx \wedge dy$. Moreover, $\omega$ is clearly closed, but not exact because 
$$
\int_{M} \omega = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} dx\,dy = 4 \pi^2;
$$
hence $\omega$ represents a nontrivial class in $H_{\mathrm{dR}}^2(M)$.

Obviously some details of the calculation are omitted, but is this correct or is there anything worth adding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that $M \ne \text{Im} \phi \cup \text{Im} \psi$, for example the point $(e^{i\pi},e^{i0}) = (-1,+1) \in M$ is not in either of those images, nor is the point $(e^{i0},e^{i\pi})=(+1,-1)$. However, it looks like those are the only two points missed out of all points in $M$.

I think you can patch that up, and once that is done, the rest of your answer should hold up.

Comment: Oops! I felt like I might be missing something. Do you have any recommendations on how to extend to those points? I could certainly define a new chart containing those points and whose transition map is one of the other coordinates plus or minus some fixed angle, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Sure, why not use more charts? One thing that one should *not* expect is that an atlas of coordinate charts be particularly efficient. For almost any application, it does not matter one whit how many charts there are in an atlas. On the contrary, it helps quite a bit sometimes to ponder the *maximal* atlas that is consistent with a given one, which from a cardinality point of view is gigantenormhumungous.

Comment: As for recommendations, you can vary the four endpoints of $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ any way whatsoever, subject only to the conditions that $0 < b-a \le 2\pi$ and $0 < d-c \le 2 \pi$.